# extract the date from the file name

Tags: python, file

I have this code :

```
import sys
import os
import re
import fnmatch
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dateutil.parser import parse as parseDate
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

file = open("0556_16-09-20114725356354 --- 16-12-2016 07-00-00.csv", 'r')
filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
timestamp = filename[-19:]
print timestamp
date = timestamp[:10] + " " + timestamp[-8:].replace("-",":")
print date
newdatefile = parseDate(date, yearfirst=True)
print newdatefile
```

My objective is to extract the date from the file name and parse it and save it in a variable. What I want to get is something like this : `16-12-2016 07-00-00`

This is the error I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 13, in <module>
    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 114, in basename
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Any ideas about what could that be ?

Comment: You're passing a file object to `os.path.basename` rather than the filename string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.basename(file)` you're passing a file object here, while it expects a string

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have `os.path` do it for you. Why not simply take the filename directly from the parameter you're passing to `open`:

```
filename = "0556_16-09-20114725356354 --- 16-12-2016 07-00-00.csv"
file = open(filename, 'r')
```

Comment: and read your file content =  file.read()